# Is it possible to create a local view in PL SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking for a solution that tell Oracle "*this query is meant to be reused like a view*" (and if I ask, it's that I don't want to/can't create a full global view if possible).

With the following minimal model (I left out other colums):

- There are *owners* which own *books*.
- A *books* have *authors* and *chapters*.
- A *chapters* have *books* (ex: chapter included in another format of the book) and *authors*.
- An *authors* have at least one _authors_related_data1_ and several _authors_related_data2_. And the same can go on with _authors_related_data3_, ..., _authors_related_dataN_.

Thus the following create statement (I did not validate them against Oracle, it's more for the understanding of the question
than for testing).

```
create table owners(  owner_id  number not null, constraint pk_owners primary key (owner_id));
create table books(   book_id   number not null, constraint pk_books primary key (book_id));
create table authors( author_id number not null, constraint pk_authors primary key (author_id));
create table chapters( chapter_id number not null, constraint pk_chapters primary key (chapter_id));

create table owned_books(
  owner_id number not null,
  book_id  number not null, 
  constraint pk_owned_books primary key (owner_id, book_id),
  constraint fk_owned_books_1 foreign key (owner_id) references owners (owner_id),
  constraint fk_owned_books_2 foreign key (book_id) references books (book_id) 
);
create table book_authors(
  book_id number not null,
  author_id  number not null, 
  constraint pk_book_authors primary key (book_id, author_id),
  constraint fk_book_authors_1 foreign key (author_id) references authors (author_id),
  constraint fk_book_authors_2 foreign key (book_id) references books (book_id) 
);
create table chapter_authors(
  chapter_id number not null,
  author_id  number not null, 
  constraint pk_chapter_authors primary key (chapter_id, author_id),
  constraint fk_chapter_authors_1 foreign key (author_id) references authors (author_id),
  constraint fk_chapter_authors_2 foreign key (chapter_id) references chapters (chapter_id) 
);
create table book_chapters(
  chapter_id number not null,
  book_id  number not null, 
  constraint pk_book_chapters primary key (chapter_id, book_id),
  constraint fk_book_chapters_1  foreign key (chapter_id) references chapters (chapter_id)
  constraint fk_book_chapters_2 foreign key (book_id) references books (book_id)  
);

create table authors_related_data1( 
  author_id number not null,
  constraint pk_authors_related_data1 primary key (author_id),
  constraint fk_authors_related_data1_1 foreign key (author_id) references authors (author_id)
);
create table authors_related_data2(
  data_id number not null,
  author_id number not null,
  constraint pk_authors_related_data2 primary key (data_id),
  constraint authors_related_data2 foreign key (author_id) references authors (author_id)
);
```

The queries (and the duplicate parts) that I want to do:

```
with v_books as (
  select books.book_id
  from owned_books 
  inner join books on books.book_id = owned_books.book_id
  where owned_books.owner_id = P_OWNER_ID
), v_authors as (
    select authors.author_id
    from v_books
    inner join book_authors on book_authors.book_id = v_books.book_id
    inner join authors on authors.author_id = book_authors.author_id
  union
    select authors.author_id
    from v_books
    inner join book_chapters on book_chapters.book_id = v_books.book_id
    inner join chapter_authors on chapter_authors.chapter_id = book_chapters.chapter_id
    inner join authors on authors.author_id = book_chapters.author_id  
)
  select authors_related_data1.*
  from   v_authors
  inner join authors_related_data1 on authors_related_data1.author_id = v_authors.author_id
;

with v_books as (
  select books.book_id
  from owned_books 
  inner join books on books.book_id = owned_books.book_id
  where owned_books.owner_id = P_OWNER_ID
), v_authors as (
    select authors.author_id
    from v_books
    inner join book_authors on book_authors.book_id = v_books.book_id
    inner join authors on authors.author_id = book_authors.author_id
  union
    select authors.author_id
    from v_books
    inner join book_chapters on book_chapters.book_id = v_books.book_id
    inner join chapter_authors on chapter_authors.chapter_id = book_chapters.chapter_id
    inner join authors on authors.author_id = book_chapters.author_id  
)
  select authors_related_data2.*
  from   v_authors
  inner join authors_related_data2 on authors_related_data2.author_id = v_authors.author_id
;
```

The first part (with ...) is the same for both queries.

A view like that would be great:

```
create view v_owned_authors as (
  with v_books as (
    select books.book_id
    from owned_books 
    inner join books on books.book_id = owned_books.book_id
  )
    (
        select authors.author_id
        from v_books
        inner join book_authors on book_authors.book_id = v_books.book_id
        inner join authors on authors.author_id = book_authors.author_id
      union
        select authors.author_id
        from v_books
        inner join book_chapters on book_chapters.book_id = v_books.book_id
        inner join chapter_authors on chapter_authors.chapter_id = book_chapters.chapter_id
        inner join authors on authors.author_id = book_chapters.author_id  
    )
;
```

The previous queries would be as simple as:

```
  select authors_related_data2.*
  from   v_owned_authors
  inner join authors_related_data2 on authors_related_data2.author_id = v_authors.author_id
  where v_owned_authors.owner_id = P_OWNER_ID
```

But:

- The set of owned books might be too big, and the view would not have the P_OWNER_ID parameter and to lessen the owned books clause. So, for performance reason I'd like to avoid the view because I don't think Oracle will be able to optimize such use case.
- For various (and legit) reasons, I can't.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what part(s) of your queries that you want to reuse.  You already appear to know about the `WITH` clause which is what I would guess you'd want to use based on your description.

Comment: It is in a PL/SQL procedure, the code is duplicated, and the `with` does not help here. Normally, if I could, I would create a view and here, I'm looking for a proper equivalent (either via cursor, etc...)

Comment: I'm still not seeing what code is duplicated in your example which makes it difficult to see the problem that we're trying to solve.  I'm not sure what "does not compile" means-- presumably, you're getting some specific error.  Is `foobar` a collection of a type defined in SQL?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from reading the query into a temporary table which you then use repeatedly throughout the procedure?

Comment: This is exactly why views exist. Why can't you create a view?

Comment: See my update for 1) an example 2) a real reason as to why I don't want to use view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a table function or a pipelined function

Here's an example of a table function from:
http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php

```
CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/

-- Build the table function itself.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab AS
  l_tab  t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows LOOP
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN l_tab;
END;
/

-- Test it.
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_tf(10))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Here's an example of a pipelined function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED AS
   r t_tf_row%rowtype;
BEGIN
  for z in (select id, desc from sometalbe) loop
    r.id := z.id;
    r.description := z.desc;
    PIPE ROW(r);   
  END LOOP;
 RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Great: it allow means to reuse the code, without the need for a view and I've performed such performance checks (simply running a for loop with/without the table block, and it seems to performs _just_ as if the query was not inlined. However, since I'm not familiar with it I can't tell if it's better than having a double for loop (probably), a view. However I'll accept your answer because it fit my need.

Comment: What you want to do is put your query inside of the function, loop through it and pipe each row.   The code above is just a sample.  I'll add a 2nd example which will give you the idea.

Comment: Yes, this work. That's why I flagged your answers as valid. The only remaining problem is performance :) (well I'm playing with a new "toy" ;)).

Comment: If the query will return a fair number of rows, the piplelined version handels memory better than the table function version.  If the tables are indexed properly, than using a single query (like the 2nd example) is most likely going to perform the best -- mainly because of context switching between sql and plsql and oracle's internal query parse/setup engine.

Answer (score 0):

Would procedure like this meet your needs?

```
  create or replace procedure p_statement (cur in out sys_refcursor)
  is   
  begin
     open cur for 
     select 1 num from dual union select 2 num from dual;
  end;
```

(I put there select from dual, instead you could replace it with your complex query and define variable to be fetch into accordingly)

the actual call could be like this:

```
   declare
    mycur sys_refcursor;
    num number;
  begin
      p_statement(mycur);
   LOOP
   FETCH mycur INTO num;
    EXIT WHEN mycur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(num);
   END LOOP;
  end;
```